# K8S - Use "Last Schedule" of a CronJob as a parameters in container command

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I created a Cronjob that is scheduled for every morning, from Monday to Friday.

```
schedule: "30 7 * * 1-5"
```

The job synchronize a database with a datawarehouse. As I do not want to sync all the database everyday, I want to be able to give two parameters in the command container's section of my CronJob ; last time the job started and now:

```
containers:
- image: xxx
  name: dwh
  command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "rake etl:sync LAST_TIME_SCHEDULED NOW"]
  resources: {}
```

How can I get the "Last Schedule" timestamp of the CronJob in this situation, and the timestamp of now ?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, although I will think about it and try to come up with some solution.

Comment: Trying to simplify things, I tried with that: 
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "start=(date -d '25 hour ago')", "end=(date)", "rake etl:sync_all $start +\"%s\" $end +\"%s\""]
But it doesn't seem that the date function and variable are interpreted...

Comment: The only solution I come up with is using *kubectl*: `kubectl get cronjobs <cronjob_name> -o=jsonpath="{.status.lastScheduleTime}"` to get *lastScheduleTime*. You would need to add kubectl to your image and create a serviceaccount with permissions to read cronjobs. You can also achieve it using `curl`